# Capture current user as variable - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, powershell, variables, azure-devops, pipeline

Background: I want to create a tag on azure resources created via bicep which is orchestrated via my azure devops pipeline(s). The tag in question I would like is the user who created them I.E the person who ran the release pipeline.

I'm not aware of any pre-defined variables that can capture the current ADO user, and I've also tried in PowerShell, however the below snippet only captures the build agent user on the microsoft hosted agent

```
$currentUserTemp=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=currentUser;]$currentUserTemp"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you get the VSID of the user who queue the pipeline:

`Build.QueuedById`

And these are the official documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-are-the-identity-variables-set